# How to send Photos to server with additional fields in Android app?

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I try to send multiple photos to server with Retrofit. I have endpoint like this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/v1/props")
Call<ModelProp> createProp(
        @Header("x-auth") String token,
        @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> photo
);
```

But I don't know how to add to this POST method additional information with:

```
int price;
String currency;
ArrayList<String> tags;
```

Can someone help me add this fields to POST with retrofit?

edit:
Array may have 1000+ elements

Comment: you could add additional information to the query string

Comment: How can I add array to query string? Is there a way?

Comment: when you make URL, you can add the query parameter to it. From the server, you would have to process those params. `HttpUrl url = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()
                .addQueryParameter("param1", "param1_value")
                .build();
`

Comment: please refer to [https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-add-query-parameters-to-every-request]

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but if I have 1000 items in array it's not a good idea to add it to a query string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Retrofit 2, You can send it extra data with the image in the following way:

**Edit:** Based on Ali Ghafari answer you can also use `PartMap`

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/v1/props")
    Call<ModelProp> createProp(@Header("x-auth") String token, 
                      @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> photo,
                      @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
List<MultipartBody.Part> parts = new ArrayList<>();    
for (int i=0; i < upFileList.size(); i++){
   parts.add(prepareFilePart("my_file["+i+"]", upFileList.get(i)));
}
Map<String, RequestBody> partMap = new HashMap<>();
partMap.put("price", createPartFromString(edtPrice.getText().toString()));
partMap.put("currency", createPartFromString(edtCurrency.getText().toString()));
partMap.put("tags", createPartFromString(new Gson().toJson(tagsArrayList));
Call<User> call = client.createProp(TokenUtils.getToken(this), partMap);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelProp>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<ModelProp> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        // consume response
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

**`prepareFilePart` method**

```
  private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, Uri fileUri){

    File file = new File(fileUri.getPath(););

    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)), file);

    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(),requestBody);
  }
```

**`createPartFromString` method**

```
public RequestBody createPartFromString(String string) {
        return RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, string);
    }
```

Comment: It looks like true, will check it with code and mark the answer. Thank you!

Comment: from where can I get getPath() method in new File(getPath(fileUri))?

Comment: `fileUri.getPath()` - gives an error onFailure: /external/images/media/63927 (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

change your interface to this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/v1/props")
Call<ModelProp> createProp(
        @Header("x-auth") String token,
        @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> photo,
        @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map  //added

);
```

and use these codes to get maps and send them to `createProp` :

```
    public Map<String, RequestBody> getMap() {
        Map<String, RequestBody> partMap = new HashMap<>();
        String authorS = author.getText().toString();
        partMap.put("price", createPartFromString(price));

        // you can put more filed to partMap

        return partMap;
     }
```

```
 public RequestBody createPartFromString(String string) {
        return RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, string);
    }
```

Comment: How to add an array to this?

Answer (score 0):

**Option1:** Use multiple `@Part` and pass your arguments normally.

```
@Multipart
@POST("/v1/props")
Call<ModelProp> createProp(
        @Header("x-auth") String token,
        @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> photo,
        @Part("price") int price,
        @Part("currency") String currency,
        @Part("tags") List<String> tags
);
```

**Option2:** Use `@PartMap` and make a `Map` include your data.

```
@Multipart
@POST("/v1/props")
Call<ModelProp> createProp(
        @Header("x-auth") String token,
        @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> photo,
        @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> dataMap
);
```

and create a map of data to pass along

```
RequestBody price = ...
RequestBody currency = ...
RequestBody tags = ...

HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();  
map.put("price", description);  
map.put("currency", place);  
map.put("tags", time);
```